# Getting AbstractMethodError while creating a connection to Oracle9 database with Tomcat 8 server

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I am getting the below error when I start the Tomcat 8 server.
I am using ojdbc14.jar and I have tried with ojdbc6.jar as well,but its not working.This is happening only with Tomcat 8. If I use Tomcat 7 then it is not throwing any exception. JRE version is 7

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2306)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
>     ... 21 more

Comment: I am using JRE version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ojdbc7.jar with Java 7, it should work.